Text from .ps file does not show up on the pdf-file
I have read in a ps.file with figures/words in a latex-file and compiled by xelatex but it does not show the alphabets and texts on figure, just the figure without alphabets and words.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{./FIG1.ps}
\end{document} 

The FIG1.ps file can be downloaded here https://home.hvl.no/ansatte/ahas/div/FIG1.ps
Thanks for your help!

Off-topic: If your tex distribution is up to date, you shouldn't use \usepackage{ucs} \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

As far as I can see the .ps (which  is not eps file but prpbably works if you rename it to .eps) does not load any font so has no text

Note that ucs and inputenc were usable some years ago with pdflatex but neither should ever be used with xelatex.

I don't see any text in the ps either.

The PS file has no text.
Unrelated to latex if you view it, eg convert to pdf with
ps2pdf FIG1.ps
Then view the PDF you get

Which matches what the posted latex document produces.
Note with xelatex you get the warnings
Package ucs Warning: ucs package ignored with utf8 based engines.

Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

So remove both of those packages.

I get this as well out. But the figure does not show up alphabets I have T, R and C. Yours does not show either. This is the problem.

@Latexfan there is no text in the FIG1.ps.  whatever software you used to make that postscript did not save any text to the file. I showed the direct view of the postscript to show the problem is unrelated to latex.

Now I have asked the cowriter and it is a FIG1.LBL file which reads in the alphabets T, C and R. How can I read the LBL file there? FIG1.LBL I can send by email if you send me an email: ahas@hvl.no . Thanks.

@Latexfan no if you want to ask a question you need to provide the data here.  but .lbl is not an standard extension so the file format could be anything,  if it is an application-specific format there may be no way for latex to read it. You should be able to generate something more portable from whetever program you are using, but theer is no tex releated question to answer here other than the answer |given that theer is no text in the file.
